# GCP Empty Response in React Native Expo App with Node Backend

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-platform, expo

I have been trying to convert speech to text with GCP. I am using Audio from expo-av on an IOS Simulator but I keep on getting empty responses from the API.

Here is my frontend function that sends the data to my Node backend

```
async function startRecording() {
    if (audioPermission == "granted") {
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true
      })
    }
    try {
      const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();
      console.log('Starting Recording')
      await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync();
      await newRecording.startAsync();
      setRecording(newRecording);
      setRecordingStatus('recording');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', error);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    try {
      if (recordingStatus === 'recording') {
        await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        const recordingUri = recording.getURI();
        console.log(recordingUri)
        const fileName = `recording-${Date.now()}.caf`;
        await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'recordings/', { intermediates: true });
        const filePath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'recordings/' + `${fileName}`
        await FileSystem.moveAsync({
          from: recordingUri,
          to: filePath
        });
        console.log(filePath)
        uploadAudio(filePath)
        const playbackObject = new Audio.Sound();
        await playbackObject.loadAsync({ uri: filePath});
        await playbackObject.playAsync();
        setRecording(null);
        setRecordingStatus('stopped');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to stop recording', error);
    }
  }

  async function handleRecordButtonPress() {
    if (recording) {
      const audioUri = await stopRecording(recording);
    } else {
      await startRecording();
    }
  }
```

I click a button that triggers the handleRecordButtonPress(), which triggers the start and stop buttons.

Here is my backend code that does the processing of the file

```
const client = new speech.SpeechClient({
    keyFilename: 'config/key.json',
});
const app = express();

// Set up multer middleware to handle file uploads
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // Maximum file size is 10 MB
  },
});


async function sendSpeechToGCP(file) {
    try {
        // Send the audio file to the Speech-to-Text API for transcription
        const [response] = await client.recognize({
            audio: {
                content: file.buffer,
            },
            config: {
                encoding: 'FLAC',
                sampleRateHertz: 16000,
                languageCode: 'en-US',
            },
        })
        console.log(response)
        const transcription = response.results.map(result => 
            result.alternatives[0].transcript).join('\n');
        console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
    }   
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

I believe the issue may be the frontend library only records in .caf extension which is problematic. Any way around this? Any advice would be appreciated. The expo library is not the best if that is the case.

I know the audio is fine because I can play it back and hear it on my simulator FYI.